# Is is possible to set the email address or name of a Google Service Account?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

Our platform is using a Google Service Account to create folders on Google Drive and share the folders with some of our end users.  Think of it as a replacement for the traditional hot folders on an ftp site.

The problems may seem minor but when the end-user sees our shared folder the owner appears as the service account email address which is pretty ugly and I'm assuming not meant for end-user viewing: "178235058172-hi96h0con2ipmnli26tn17bdodb5ba4c@developer.gserviceaccount.com".  It's also the sender email address when the user receives the "I've shared an item with you" email when we share the folder with them.

Is there any way to have the email address be the name of our service? or a way to change the name of the owner of the shared folder?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change the name of the service account.   Nor is it possible to give it a name.

You could crate a dummy gmail account for the company.  grant it owner.  Give the service account write access to it.

However if the service account shares the folder with someone its still going to show as the service account has shared the item with them.

Only real work around I can think of would be to use Oauth2, authenticate the code once so you have a refresh token.  Then use the refresh token to gain access faking a service account.   Its not truly a service account and if something happens to the refresh token you are going to have to reauthentcate.

Comment: doesn't work: there is no 'password' for this account and attempting to reset it does not seem to work